# Yii2 css/site.css and js not found (404)

Tags: javascript, css, xampp, http-status-code-404, yii2-advanced-app

I got a task to write a module in a project which we are currently working at my workplace. I pulled down the project, set the vhost, made an init and a migrate. The project works fine but there is no style and javascript at all. With the developer tools I can see in the html source that it can't find css/site.css and the javascript files (404 not found). I am using xampp and advanced project template.

### I have tried:

- to check the folder and there is a css/site.css file
- to give permission to write and read site.css for everyone
- to check the AppAsset class. But it must be good because in the assets folder there are the generated css and js files

  ```
  class AppAsset extends AssetBundle {
  public $basePath = '@webroot';
  public $baseUrl = '@web';
  public $css = [
      'css/site.css',
  ];
  public $js = [
       'js/filehandler.js'
  ];
   public $depends = [
      'yii\web\YiiAsset',
      'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
  ];
  }
  ```
- to check my apache httpd-vhost.conf

  ```
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/site/frontend/web"
    ServerName site.local
    ServerAlias site.local
    <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/site/frontend/web">
      RewriteEngine on
      # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !­f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !­d
      # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
      RewriteRule . index.php
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
          AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- there is a beginbody and an endbody at the main layout file, and the *AppAsset::register($this);* too.

Please help me guys. Why can't the webbrowser see those files? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Solved: there was a missing .htacces file at the frontend/web directory. If you have the same problem, I recommend to use this: [yii2 github example project from the developers](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-shop/blob/master/frontend/web/.htaccess)